# Setting up Hairpin NAT on Edge Router Lite 3

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, nat

I have my router set-up to forward all traffic from internal IP of `192.168.6.180`  through my VPN account.  This works perfectly for that purpose, however, I now need a way of accessing that PC from outside my network.

Since I have the internal IP set to route both incoming and outgoing traffic through vtun1 if simply forwarding a port on my router to this internal IP is not sufficient since the packet would be coming from WAN and not VTUN1.

Comment: If you want to access a PC from outside of your intranet then you have to forward the port to that PC's intranet ip address and then access it from router's public ip address

Comment: Yes, but I believe I am hitting an issue since I have that internal IP going out on vtun1 of my router instead of my WAN.  And incoming traffic would hit the WAN interface not the vtun1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.